# VideoJuego en Unity C sharp

Tags: c#, vscode, unity, unity3d, unity2d

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> UIManager.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/UIManager.cs:13)

Tengo un error UIManager.cs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te hace falta inicializar las variables antes de invocar Update, puedes usar los métodos que te dicen en el siguiente link, como try .. catch. https://saturncloud.io/blog/what-is-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error-in-cloud-projects-and-how-to-fix-it/#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%9CObject%20reference%20not%20set,object%20that%20doesn't%20exist.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes, usa texto para compartir código. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] y leer [ask]